# How do I programmatically add elements to a ConfigurationElementCollection?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, configuration, app-config

I'm trying to unit test a custom [`ConfigurationElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx), but I'm having a problem populating the collection programmatically.  When I call [`BaseAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19tyhxbx.aspx), I get the following exception:

> ConfigurationErrorsException : The element 'add' has been locked in a higher level configuration.

However, this problem only appears when running multiple tests.  Consider these two tests:

```
private Fixture Fixtures = new Fixture();  // AutoFixtures

[Test]
public void test1()
{
    var tc = Fixtures.CreateAnonymous<TenantCollection>();
    var t = Fixtures.CreateAnonymous<Tenant>();
    tc.Add(t);
}

[Test]
public void test2()
{
    var tc = Fixtures.CreateAnonymous<TenantCollection>();
    var t = Fixtures.CreateAnonymous<Tenant>();
    tc.Add(t);
}
```

Each individual test passes when executed alone.  When run together, the locking exception is thrown.

What's going on here?  How can I either unlock the collection or work around that lock?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure how `ConfigurationElement` locking works, but I did find a workaround that seems fine for unit testing at least: before adding new items, set `LockItem` to false.

So in my custom `ConfigurationElementCollection` I have the method `Add()` (which I'm calling in the OP).  It needs to be modified to look like this:

```
public class TenantCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public void Add(Tenant element)
    {
        LockItem = false;  // the workaround
        BaseAdd(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can, as well, override the IsReadOnly method from your TenantCollection implementation and return false